# Wordpress Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I am trying to align the content of the website but some reason the content after a few set is getting disaligned.

[image]

Link: http://play.mink7.com/cadabams/team/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI now  `clear:both` of your `#page-left-content-holder .entry-content h3.title-name`

as like this

```
#page-left-content-holder .entry-content h3.title-name{
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by making a div and and place the image and content of one user and assign the `width:100%;`